# JAVA: writing xml using Xmlserializer - context problems

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to write an XML doc and POST it but cannot get the format of the doc correct when using XmlSerializer (I am working in Android Studio).

The XML I wish to write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ser:serviceParameters xmlns:ser="http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/serviceParameters">
  <ser:parameters>
      <ser:parameter key="action">
         <ser:value>add</ser:value>
      </ser:parameter>
  </ser:parameters>
  <ser:patronIdentifier lastName="LastName" patronHomeUbId="1@DB" patronId="12345">
     <ser:authFactor type="B">150</ser:authFactor>
  </ser:patronIdentifier>
  <ser:definedParameters xsi:type="pat:bookbagRecordsType" xlns:pat="http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/patronPreferences" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <pat:record>
          <pat:bibId>54414</pat:bibId>
          <pat:databaseCode>LOCAL</pat:databaseCode>
     </pat:record>
  </ser:definedParameters>
</ser:serviceParameters>
```

And this is the code I have to produce XML:

```
private static String writeXml(String surname, String barcode, String thisbibid){
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("ser", "serviceParameters");
        serializer.attribute("http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/serviceParameters", "xmlns", "ser");
        serializer.startTag("ser", "parameters");
        serializer.startTag("ser", "parameter");
        serializer.attribute("ser", "action", "add");
        serializer.endTag("ser", "parameter");
        serializer.endTag("ser", "parameters");
        serializer.startTag("ser", "patronIdentifier");
        serializer.attribute("", "lastName", surname);
            serializer.attribute("", "patronHomeUbId", "local");
            serializer.attribute("", "patronId", "12345");
            serializer.startTag("ser", "authFactor");
                serializer.attribute("", "type", "B");
        serializer.text("150");
            serializer.endTag("ser", "authFactor");
        serializer.endTag("ser", "patronIdentifier");
        serializer.startTag("ser", "definedParameters");
        serializer.attribute("http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/patronPreferences", "xmlns", "pat");
        serializer.attribute("pat", "bookbagRecordsType", "xsi:type");
        serializer.startTag("pat", "record");
            serializer.startTag("pat", "bibId");
                serializer.text(thisbibid);
            serializer.endTag("pat", "bibId");
            serializer.startTag("pat", "databaseCode");
                serializer.text("LOCAL");
            serializer.endTag("pat", "databaseCode");
        serializer.endTag("pat", "record");
        serializer.endTag("ser", "definedParameters");
        serializer.endTag("ser", "serviceParameters");
        serializer.endDocument();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But the String output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><n0:serviceParameters n1:xmlns="ser" xmlns:n0="ser" xmlns:n1="http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/serviceParameters"><n0:parameters><n0:parameter n0:action="add" /></n0:parameters><n0:patronIdentifier lastName="LastName" patronHomeUbId="local" patronId="12345"><n0:authFactor type="B">150</n0:authFactor></n0:patronIdentifier><n0:definedParameters n2:xmlns="pat" n3:bookbagRecordsType="xsi:type" xmlns:n2="http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/patronPreferences" xmlns:n3="pat"><n3:record><n3:bibId>54414</n3:bibId><n3:databaseCode>LOCAL</n3:databaseCode></n3:record></n0:definedParameters></n0:serviceParameters>
```

I have tried altering order of the .attribute elements but cannot get the prefixes right.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Which package is the Xml.newSerializer() ?? I'm trying to reproduce your error, apparently your code is OK. It should return the expected XML.

Comment: import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;  I think that's what you're asking for.  The code does not throw any error it's the formatting of the XML that is wrong, with the n0 prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the setPrefix method and lots of trial and error I got the format of the XML to match what's required.

```
private static String writeXml(String surname, String barcode, String thisbibid){
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.setPrefix("ser", "http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/serviceParameters");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:serviceParameters");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:parameters");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:parameter");
        serializer.attribute("", "key", "action");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:value");
        serializer.text("add");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:value");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:parameter");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:parameters");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:patronIdentifier");
        serializer.attribute("", "lastName", surname);
        serializer.attribute("", "patronHomeUbId", "local");
        serializer.attribute("", "patronId", "12345");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:authFactor");
        serializer.attribute("", "type", "B");
        serializer.text("150");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:authFactor");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:patronIdentifier");
        serializer.setPrefix("pat", "http://www.endinfosys.com/Voyager/patronPreferences");
        serializer.setPrefix("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        serializer.startTag("", "ser:definedParameters");
        serializer.attribute("", "xsi:type", "pat:bookbagRecordsType");
        serializer.startTag("", "pat:record");
            serializer.startTag("", "pat:bibId");
                serializer.text(thisbibid);
            serializer.endTag("", "pat:bibId");
            serializer.startTag("", "pat:databaseCode");
                serializer.text("LOCAL");
            serializer.endTag("", "pat:databaseCode");
        serializer.endTag("", "pat:record");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:definedParameters");
        serializer.endTag("", "ser:serviceParameters");
        serializer.endDocument();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Having to set the prefix and then "hard code" it in the start/end tags was not clear from the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html.

Now to move foward to the next stumbling block ;)